# Django - DoesNotExist Error - How can I say to allow this?

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models like this:

```
class Collar(models.Model):
    num_tags = models.BigIntegerField()

class Dog(models.Model):
    num_legs = models.BigIntegerField()
    collar =  models.OneToOneField(Collar,null=True,blank=True)
```

Whenever I try to do something like:

```
dog = Dog.objects.all()[0]
if dog.collar:
    #do something ...
```

I get a DoesNotExist Error on the line: if dog.collar.

How can I tell Django that this is ok?  That a collar won't always exist and I want to check for its existence without triggering an error?

Comment: Have you modified your model since the tables where created with `syncdb`?

Comment: Yeah! Probably there is no table created to the models yet...

Comment: Please, post the debug data here. So, it'll be really easy to solve your problem ;)

Comment: @Jayme: I suspect `Dog.collar`'s `OneToOneField` didn't have `null=True` option when the table was created, not that the table didn't exist.

Comment: @André Caron: It can be too. But can be lots of other things. So, we need to wait for more info about the error...

Comment: This is a very simple Django situation. I'm surprised to see all the varying answers here. `collar` is a foreign key to `Collar` on `Dog`. To get the value of the attribute, Django is calling the functional equivalent of `Collar.objects.get(dog=dog)`. As the author said, there's no collar, so `Collar.DoesNotExist` is raised. The only way around this is to wrap the code in a `try...except` block. Done deal.

Comment: I was trying to make a toy example to illustrate the problem, my real models are many pages long, and I have managed set to False.  Since it looks like my understanding of how the models work seems to be correct, there must just be a bug or a synch issue somewhere.  I'll start looking for that.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `try..except` block:

```
try:
   if dog.collar:
       # Do something
except Collar.DoesNotExist:
   # Do something else
```

Also, never assume that `all()` will always return *something*. In ideal circumstances, sure, but life is never ideal. You need to catch the potential `IndexError` with a statement like that, and have a contingency plan in place:

```
try:
    dog = Dog.ojbects.all()[0]
except IndexError:
    # Contingency plan so website doesn't explode
```

Comment: This is the right answer to the question so +1. However, this is the wrong question. You should not have an id for collar if collar doesn't exist. The OP data is corrupted, and that is the problem. I'd check the ondelete rules.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your model definition has changed since you first created your tables using `manage.py syncdb`.

Your initial `Dog` model probably looked like:

```
class Dog(models.Model):
    num_legs = models.BigIntegerField()
    collar =  models.OneToOneField(Collar)
```

Then, you created your tables using `manage.py syncdb`, which created the `Dog` and `Collar` model tables.

Finally, you decided `Dog.collar` should be optional to allow constructs such as:

```
dog = Dog.ojbects.all()[0]
if dog.collar:
    #do something ...
```

and modified your model to:

```
class Dog(models.Model):
    num_legs = models.BigIntegerField()
    collar =  models.OneToOneField(Collar,null=True,blank=True)
```

then updated your models using `manage.py syncdb` and got caught with the classic error with Django because of a mislabled command: the `syncdb` command *does not synchronize tables with the model definitions*, it *creates the tables*.

I suspect that if you drop the tables associated to `Dog` and re-run `syncdb`, your code snipped will start working.

Answer (score -2):

Have you checked this?

```
if getattr(dog, collar):
```

And one of possible ways --- deriving from OneToOneField with overriding .to_python() by adding try/except block.

Comment: Come on folks. If that was the case, the error would be an `AttributeError` not `DoesNotExist`. This answer is completely not applicable.

Comment: Why overriding `.to_python()` in such way that it will return `None` if there isn't `collar` is not applicable?